# Array to string conversion in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this error in laravel 5.5 :

> Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `channel_txt_posts`
>   (`channel_id`, `subcategoty_id`, `message_id`, `media_id`,
>   `media_accesshash`, `media_kind`, `body`, `view`) values (370, 1, 578,
>   5800649510354004639, 6584445945021826373, 1, "@funn_gram", 252))

while it seems to be true because of when I use the sql query in phpmyadmin it works without errors.

```
 insert into `channel_txt_posts` (`channel_id`, `subcategoty_id`, `message_id`, `media_id`, `media_accesshash`, `media_kind`, `body`, `view`) values (370, 1, 578, 5800649510354004639, 6584445945021826373, 1, "@funn_gram", 252)
```

I used both laravel query builder and orm and both have the same error.

```
Channel_txt_posts::create([
    'channel_id' => $channel_id,
    'subcategoty_id' => 1,
    'message_id' => $ids,
    'body'=> "df",
    'view' => $viewcount,
    ]); 



$data = new Channel_txt_posts;
$data->channel_id = $channel_id;
$data->subcategoty_id = 1;
$data->message_id = $ids;
$data->body = json_encode($myName);
$data->view = $viewcount;
$data->save();
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think `json_encode($myName);` causing the issue. Try with static value.

Comment: I used $myname before. and no change in the error. thanks.

Comment: Try with something like `$data->body = 'mrmrn';`

Comment: Share model `Channel_txt_posts` ?

Comment: Also share migration of table `channel_txt_posts` ?

Comment: `$data->message_id = $ids`. `$ids` is an array?

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy, I checked every parameter and the ids was an array. thank you.
urfusion and user2486 thank you.